# frida modify static param as ArrayList

Tags: frida

```
public class OBDSportsModelManager {
    public static ArrayList<DataArray> mDiagnosisCommand;
    public boolean getData() {
        mDiagnosisCommand = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String dataArray : this.commandIDs) {
            mDiagnosisCommand.add(new DataArray(dataArray));
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I want to add some more item to the 'mDiagnosisCommand',

by using this code:

```
sports.getData.implementation = function(){
    Log.v("hook-sports", "try to add obd commands!");
    var ret = this.getData();
    var DataArray = Java.use("com.obd2.comm.DataArray");
    var items = DataArray.$new("0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x42");

    this.mDiagnosisCommand.add(items);  // not working!!!

    Log.v("hook-sports", "hook done!");

    return ret;
}
```

but doesn't works well.

I googled frida ArrayList add items without any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You are using `this.mDiagnosisCommand` but the field is a static field, therefore it belongs to the class `OBDSportsModelManager` and not to the class instance `this`.
2. By calling `this.mDiagnosisCommand` you only get the Frida object representing this field, not the field value itself. If you want the `ArrayList` referenced by a field you have to add `.value`.

Considering both problems the following lines should work (after correcting the class name):

```
// correct the class name in the next line
var cls = Java.use("<full.name.to>.OBDSportsModelManager"); 
cls.mDiagnosisCommand.value.add(items);
```

Comment: always forgot the VALUE as a starter for using frida thanks.
btw, I tried using this or Java.use, both works well.